# Comparing closures of function spaces with respect to distinct topologies

Tags: general-topology, continuity, differential-topology

Let $F$ be a family of $C^1$-diffeomorphisms in $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$, where $M$ is a closed (compact and boundaryless) manifold.

On $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ we can consider both the weak $C^0$ and the weak $C^1$ topologies, which I'll call $\tau_0$ and $\tau_1$ from now on.

I wanted to check how the closures of $F$ with respect to these two topologies are related, and it seems to me that they are the same, which I find somewhat hard to believe. Can anyone point to a flaw in my reasoning?

I'll write $\mathrm{Cl}_{i}(F)$ to denote the closure of $H$ with respect to the topology $\tau_i$. Now, $\tau_1 \subset \tau_0$, hence every closed set with respect to $\tau_1$ is also closed with respect to $\tau_0$. Since the closure of $F$ is the intersection of every closed set containing $H$, it follows that $\mathrm{Cl}_{0}(F) \subset \mathrm{Cl}_{1}(F)$.

On the other hand, by choosing a Riemannian metric on $M$ with distance function $d$, both these topologies have associated metrics
$$d_0(f,g) = \max_{x \in M} d(f(x), g(x)),$$
$$d_1(f,g) = \max_{x \in M} d(f(x), g(x)) + \max_{x \in M}\|df_x - dg_x\|$$

So, if $f \in \mathrm{Cl}_{1}(F)$ there is a sequence $f_n \in F$ with $d_1(fn, f) \to 0$, which implies, in particular, that $\max d(f(x)_n, f(x)) = d_0(f,g) \to 0$, hence $f \in\mathrm{Cl}_{0}(F)$. Thus the inclusion $\mathrm{Cl}_{1}(F) \subset \mathrm{Cl}_{0}(F)$ also holds, and we have equality of closures.

Ain't that a bit strange? What is worse, if $F$ is a family of $C^r$-diffeomorphisms then the same arguments seem to show that the closures $\mathrm{Cl}_{i}(F)$ are all the same, for $i = 0, 1, \cdots, r$. Moreover, if the family $F$ is uniformly equicontinuous, for example, then $\mathrm{Cl}_{0}(F)$ is compact, but since the $C^r$-topology $\tau_r$ is smaller than the $C^0$-topology, any open covering of $F$ by opens in $\tau_r$ is an open covering with respect to $\tau_0$, hence has a finite subcovering. This means a simple property like equicontinuity, which doesn't even evolve derivatives, implies compactness in a whole bunch of other topologies, all of which take differentiability into account. Sounds like bit of a stretch to me.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: For clearity, let me give formal definitions for the topologies I'm talking about. We fix an atlas $\{(\phi_\alpha, U_\alpha)\}$. Given a diffeo $f: M \to M$, charts $(\phi_\alpha, U_\alpha), (\phi_\beta, U_\beta)$, a compact subset $K \subset M$ such that $K \subset U_\alpha$ and $f(K) \subset U_\beta$, and a posite real number $\epsilon$, the weak $C^r$ subbasic neighbourhood of $f$ is the set
$$\mathcal{N}^r(f; \alpha, \beta, K, \epsilon)$$
of all diffeos $g: M \to M$ such that $g(K) \subset U_\beta$ and
$$\max_{x \in K}\|D^k(\phi_\beta f \phi_\alpha^{-1})(x) - D^k(\phi_\beta g \phi_\alpha^{-1})(x)\| < \epsilon,$$
for $k = 0, 1, \cdots, r$. By varying $f, \alpha, \beta, K$ and $\epsilon$ we get a subbasis for a topology $\tau_r$ on $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$, called the weak $C^r$ topology.

As for my claim that $\tau_1 \subset \tau_0$, notice that $\mathcal{N}^1(f; \alpha, \beta, K, \epsilon) \subset \mathcal{N}^0(f; \alpha, \beta, K, \epsilon)$, hence every basic open for $\tau_1$ is contained in a basic open for $\tau_0$. Therefore every set that is open with respect to $\tau_1$ is also open with respect to $\tau_0$.

Comment: Assuming your claim about the metrics is true, it seems that convergence with respect to $d_1$ implies convergence with respect to $d_0$ but not conversely, so $\tau_0 \subset \tau_1$ rather than the reverse, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm considering the weak (aka compact open) $C^r$ topologies, which are always metrizable, as opposed to the strong (aka Whitney) $C^r$ topologies. I didn't mention it because, since $M$ is compact, the compact-open and Whitney topologies are the same. As for the explicity metrics I choose, I found then on the wikipedia article on [diffeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Topology).  I edited my question to add further clarifications on my claim that the reverse inclusion $\tau_1 \subset \tau_0$ also holds.